# Lazy evaluation of dict values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lazy-evaluation

Suppose I have the following dict `d={'a': heavy_expression1, 'b': heavy_expression2}`.

How can I wrap the expressions, so that they are evaluated once they are accessed and after  this no evaluation is performed?

```
d['a'] # only here heavy_expression1 is executed
d['a'] # no execution here, already calculated
```

Do I need to use `lambda` or generators?

Comment: you can pass `global` variable inside `heavy_expression1` as `executed = True` and use it as `if condition`

Comment: Why not use a class with [cached properties](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property) instead of a bare dict?

Comment: Quick idea: Have all relevant values of the dict be initialized to `None`, then query the dict through a handler function which replaces `None` with the evaluated expressions as encountered during runtime. The expressions would live inside the handler function, not the dict.

Comment: Are the two heavy_expressions really different, or do they involve the key and just differ by that?

Comment: Why use a dict at all here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A version with lambdas:

```
class LazyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, lazies):
        self.lazies = lazies
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = self.lazies[key]()
        return value

d = LazyDict({'a': lambda: print('heavy_expression1') or 1,
              'b': lambda: print('heavy_expression2') or 2})
print(d['a'])
print(d['a'])
print(d['b'])
print(d['b'])
```

Output:

```
heavy_expression1
1
1
heavy_expression2
2
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be interrupting the `__getitem__` method in subclass and do the caching there:

```
class LazyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.cache = {}

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if item in self.cache:
            return self.cache[item]
        result = super().__getitem__(item)()

        self.cache[item] = result
        return result
```

Here is the test case with functions: (*lambda* perfectly fits here if you don't want to define functions)

```
def heavy_expresion1():
    print('heavy expression1 is calculated')
    return 10

def heavy_expresion2():
    print('heavy expression2 is calculated')
    return 20

d = LazyDict({'a': heavy_expresion1, 'b': heavy_expresion2})
print(d)

print(d['a'])
print(d['a'])

print(d['b'])
print(d['b'])
```

output :

```
{'a': <function heavy_expresion1 at 0x000001AFE783ED30>, 'b': <function heavy_expresion2 at 0x000001AFE8036940>}
heavy expression1 is calculated
10
10
heavy expression2 is calculated
20
20
```